# Windows Explorer: group by tags, but show subfolders first?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, tags

I use tags for organizing my photos, specifically I sort photos by date and group by tag (ascending, so A at the top to Z at the bottom). However, when I apply this view to a photo folder, any subfolders appear all the way at the bottom in a group labelled "Unspecified", even after tags beginning with Z.

[Here's an example of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Tli.png)

Ideally, I'd like to have subfolders appear right at the top, to make navigating easier. Is there a way to do either of these things:

- Change some setting/registry tweak so that "Unspecified" is the first group rather than the last?
- Give folders their own tag by default, for instance "[Folder]", such that they will sort before any alphanumeric tags anyway?

I'm not really concerned about the other untagged files that show up in "Unspecified", just the subfolders, so either option works for me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does Sort by Name Ascending look like?  I think what you are seeing is the result of Sort by Tags which overrides placing Folders at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle the order being **`Z - A`**, The easiest way is to change the **GroupBy** order from **`Ascending`** to **`Descending`**.

[image]